# Pandas encode data field

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a html table from Wikipedia into a Panda Dataframe. However, the encoding of a character to ascii is falling and I don't now how to overcome this error.

```
df_list = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Detroit_Pistons_seasons', header=0)
df = df_list[1]
print (df)
```

The error message I got is the following:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 149: ordinal not in range(128)`
```

I tried to convert the values to a string using the function `Dataframe.astype()` but I got the same end result. Any help on how to solve this issue is really appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: The [`encoding` kwarg of `pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) might be relevant.

Comment: Sorry but I am new to Python. Could you please be more specific on how I could potentially use enconding to solve the issue ?

Comment: I'm not sure because I'm not familiar with the subject, but it's possible that you can pass `encoding='utf8'` which might cause the parser to not use the `ascii` codec (from which the error message is raised). I believe the parser should be smart enough to determine the right encoding on its own, that's why I'm not sure that something like this would work. But worth a try.

Comment: I got the same error when I specify `enconding='utf-8'` `df_list = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Detroit_Pistons_seasons',encoding='utf8')
df = df_list[1]
print (df1)` -> `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 78: ordinal not in range(128)`